# Error using '/directoryObjects/validateProperties' API: Invalid entity type provided

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

When using the [directoryObjects/validateProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryobject-validateproperties?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) API for creating/validating AD Group properties, a 400 error is returned indicating 'Invalid entity provided. Supported entities include: Group'.  I have confirmed that the only entityType I am providing in the request is 'Group' or 'group'.

```
{ code: 'Request_BadRequest',
 message:
  'Invalid entity type provided. Supported entities include: Group.',
 innerError:
  { 'request-id': '4949163f-43c4-42e8-b016-436af61e4eb5',
    date: '2020-06-11T10:29:08' } } }
```

The error occurs in both /v1.0 and /beta versions of the MS Azure AD API, with the body/payload stringified or not.

I am not exactly sure what is expected. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have validated the properties by using the same JSON Data from the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryobject-validateproperties?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-1-successful-validation-request) in the Graph explorer and it worked for me.

This is the below data which I have given

```
{
    "entityType": "Group",
    "displayName": "Myprefix_test_mysuffix",
    "mailNickname": "Myprefix_test_mysuffix",
    "onBehalfOfUserId": "1ab4e79f-5f52-44b8-8c72-7d03c05e6ff4"
}
```

And I am hitting the V1.0 endpoint
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/validateProperties

Try with my sample copying it change the onBehalfOfUserID to your userID and hit the same Http call in Graph Explorer.

Comment: The issue I can confirm is that I was stringifying the body before passing it in my POST request.  It is possible the request library I was using was stringifying the string again resulting in double quote-escaped string.  But here's the question I have: do you get the HTTP response code for valid requests?  I get a null or empty response while an invalid response returns the expected HTTP response code 422.  Thanks you for your response.

Comment: I have got 204 HTTP code when it got validated successfully which means "No Content" , which means no response body :)-